# Generalizing von Staudt's synthetic construction of the complex numbers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry

Starting from the real projective plane described synthetically/axiomatically, it is possible to construct the complex projective plane directly without passing through coordinates: one adjoins two new conjugate points for each fixed-point-free ("elliptic") projective involution on a real line.  This is due to von Staudt (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204688/a-geometric-construction-of-the-complex-projective-plane)).

In volume 2 of Veblen-Young's treatise *Projective Geometry*, it appears to be suggested that this method could be used more generally to construct projective planes over quadratic field extensions.  Specifically, on page 9 they say

> There is a ... method of introducing imaginaries in geometry without the use of coördinates... due to von Staudt... The reader will find it an excellent exercise to generalize the von Staudt theory so as to obtain the result stated in Proposition $K_2$, Chap. IV, Vol. I.

The statement of Proposition $K_2$, Chap. IV, Vol. I (page 260) is

> If any finite number of involutions are given in a space $S$ satisfying Assumptions A, E, P, there exists a space $S'$ of which $S$ is a subspace, such that all the given involutions have double points in $S'$.

Their Assumptions A, E, P essentially say that we are talking about Pappian projective spaces, which can therefore be coordinatized by fields.  Their proof of Proposition $K_2$ then proceeds by constructing a field extension.

My question is, (how) can von Staudt's method be generalized to apply to all Pappian projective spaces?  I.e. how to do the "excellent exercise"?  The problem seems to be in distinguishing between the two conjugate points that have to be adjoined for an elliptic involution.  The only way I have seen to make this precise is to assume an additional structure of "sense" or "order" in the projective space, which seems to correspond to the underlying field being ordered.  But what about projective spaces over unordered (e.g. finite) fields?